# Dont want to see few modified files when git status

Tags: git

During test runs, many files got modified.
When I hit 'git status', there are plenty of files listed as modified.
Neither i want to add/commit them nor I WANT TO SEE THEM in list of modified files during status check.

How to I ignore/hide them ?

Found below solution based on comments received:
I safe_delete (refactor) most of the files and manually delete all remaining .pyc. 
I totally ignored why earlier coder pushed .pyc, logs, reports to repo...

Comment: Why are your tests modifying tracked files? in what way are they modified (please edit the question to show)? Are you looking for `git checkout .` or `git reset HEAD --hard` ?

Comment: You can simply add these files to .gitignore. see: https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/ignoring-files

Comment: @aydinugur `files listed as modified` you cannot ignore tracked files

Comment: @AD7six you are right, then I don't understand why he has tracked files that he don't want to keep track of them. The question is unclear.

Comment: @AD7six, all most all files are .pyc and a log file.

Comment: @JayadevBS why are pyc and log files committed to the repository? _please edit the question as already asked_

Answer (score 1):

You should not add generated files (e.g. test results) to Git.
After removing these files from Git with `git rm`, simply add them (or their parent directory) to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.gitignore` file to ignore some file with extension or in specific directory, there are many templates here http://gitignore.io/